# If f is a real function in $H^2\mathbb(D)$ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers, hardy-spaces

I want to prove that if $f$ is a REAL function in the Hardy space $H^2\mathbb(D)$ then $f$ is contant. 
We know that if $f\in H^2\mathbb(D)$ then $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$ where $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.
Since $f$ is real then $f=\overline{f}$ hence:
$$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\overline{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n}=\overline{a_0}+\overline{a_1z}+\overline{a_2z^2}+...$$
To prove that $f$ is constant i have to show that $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in
\mathbb{D}$ ie: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nz^{n-1}=0$$ which leads to prove that: $$a_1=a_2=...=0$$
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are functions in $H^2(D)$ required to be analytic on $D$?

Comment: They are holomorphic on the unit disk.

Comment: In that case just use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Since $f$ is real then $v\equiv0$ and $f(x,y)=u(x,y)$, for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ Thus, $f_x=u_x$ and $f_y=u_y$. By Cauchy-Riemann equation, we know that: $u_x=v_y=0$ and that $u_y=-v_x=0$. Thus, $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$

Comment: This has nothing to do with $H^2$ by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f \in H^2(D)$, then $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disc $D$. If $f$ is real, then $f(D)$ is not open, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: i can't see why $f(D)$ can't be open. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Open mapping theorem in complex analysis

Comment: $f : U → C$  is a non-constant holomorphic function, then f is an open map.

Comment: We have: $f:D\rightarrow D$ is holomorphic. Since $f$ is real then $f(D)=\overline{f(D})$ is not open ie: the image of the open disk D by f is not open. The converse of the "open mapping theorem" shows that $f$ is constant. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

A function $f \in L^2(T)$ ($T$=unit circle) is the boundary function of an element of $H^2(D)$ iff
$$
             \int_{T} f(z)z^{n}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta})e^{i(n+1)\theta}d\theta = 0, \;\;\; n \ge 0.
$$
If that boundary function is real a.e., then
$$
       \overline{\int_{T}f(e^{i\theta})e^{i(n+1)\theta}d\theta}=\int_{T}f(e^{i\theta})e^{-i(n+1)\theta}d\theta=0,\;\;\; n \ge 0.
$$
Combining these two gives a function $f\in L^2(T)$ with Fourier coefficients that are all zero, except possibly for $\int_{T}f(e^{i\theta})d\theta$. So $f$ must be constant a.e.. on $T$.